# Bounding Box from VNDetectRectangleRequest is not correct size when used as child VC

Tags: ios, swift, rectangles, apple-vision, cvpixelbuffer

I am trying to use `VNDetectRectangleRequest` from Apple's Vision framework to automatically grab a picture of a card. However when I convert the points to draw the rectangle, it is misshapen and does not follow the rectangle is it should. I have been following this [article](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/scanning-credit-cards-with-computer-vision-on-ios-c3f4d8912de4) pretty closely

One major difference is I am embedding my CameraCaptureVC in another ViewController so that the card will be scanned only when it is in this smaller window.

Below is how I set up the camera vc in the parent vc (called from viewDidLoad).

```
func configureSubviews() {
    clearView.addSubview(cameraVC.view)
    cameraVC.view.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdges()
    self.addChild(cameraVC)
    cameraVC.didMove(toParent: self)
}
```

Below is the code to draw the rectangle

```
func createLayer(in rect: CGRect) {
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.frame = rect
    maskLayer.cornerRadius = 10
    maskLayer.opacity = 0.75
    maskLayer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    maskLayer.borderWidth = 5.0

    previewLayer.insertSublayer(maskLayer, at: 1)
}

func removeMask() {
    if let sublayer = previewLayer.sublayers?.first(where: { $0 as? CAShapeLayer != nil }) {
        sublayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
}

func drawBoundingBox(rect : VNRectangleObservation) {
    let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: 0, y: -finalFrame.height)

    let scale = CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: finalFrame.width, y: finalFrame.height)

    let bounds = rect.boundingBox.applying(scale).applying(transform)

    createLayer(in: bounds)
}

func detectRectangle(in image: CVPixelBuffer) {
    let request = VNDetectRectanglesRequest { (request: VNRequest, error: Error?) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let results = request.results as? [VNRectangleObservation],
                let rect = results.first else { return }
            self.removeMask()
            self.drawBoundingBox(rect: rect)
        }
    }
    request.minimumAspectRatio = 0.0
    request.maximumAspectRatio = 1.0
    request.maximumObservations = 0
    let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: image, options: [:])
    try? imageRequestHandler.perform([request])
}
```

This is my result. The red rectangle should follow the borders of the card but it is much too short and the origin is not at the top of the card even.

[image]

I have tried changing values in the `drawBoundingBox` function but nothing seems to help. I have also tried converting the bounds in a different way like below but it is the same result, and changing these values gets hacky.

```
    let scaledHeight: CGFloat = originalFrame.width / finalFrame.width * finalFrame.height
    let boundingBox = rect.boundingBox
    let x = finalFrame.width * boundingBox.origin.x
    let height = scaledHeight * boundingBox.height
    let y = scaledHeight * (1 - boundingBox.origin.y) - height
    let width = finalFrame.width * boundingBox.width

    let bounds = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
    createLayer(in: bounds)
```

Would appreciate any help. Maybe since I am embedding it as a child VC I need to transform the coordinates a second time? I tried something like this to no avail but maybe I did it wrong or was missing something

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First let's look at `boundingBox`, which is a "normalized" rectangle. Apple says

> The coordinates are normalized to the dimensions of the processed image, with the origin at the image's lower-left corner.

This means that:

- The `origin` is at the bottom-left, not the top-left
- The `origin.x` and `width` are in terms of a fraction of the entire image's width
- The `origin.y` and `height` are in terms of a fraction of the entire image's height

Hopefully this diagram makes it clearer:

| What you are used to | What Vision returns |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Your function above converts `boundingBox` to the coordinates of `finalFrame`, which I assume is the entire view's frame. That is much larger than your small `CameraCaptureVC`.

Also, your `CameraCaptureVC`'s preview layer probably has a `aspectFill` video gravity. You will also need to account for the overflowing parts of the displayed image.

Try this converting function instead.

```
func getConvertedRect(boundingBox: CGRect, inImage imageSize: CGSize, containedIn containerSize: CGSize) -> CGRect {
    
    let rectOfImage: CGRect
    
    let imageAspect = imageSize.width / imageSize.height
    let containerAspect = containerSize.width / containerSize.height
    
    if imageAspect > containerAspect { /// image extends left and right
        let newImageWidth = containerSize.height * imageAspect /// the width of the overflowing image
        let newX = -(newImageWidth - containerSize.width) / 2
        rectOfImage = CGRect(x: newX, y: 0, width: newImageWidth, height: containerSize.height)
        
    } else { /// image extends top and bottom
        let newImageHeight = containerSize.width * (1 / imageAspect) /// the width of the overflowing image
        let newY = -(newImageHeight - containerSize.height) / 2
        rectOfImage = CGRect(x: 0, y: newY, width: containerSize.width, height: newImageHeight)
    }
    
    let newOriginBoundingBox = CGRect(
    x: boundingBox.origin.x,
    y: 1 - boundingBox.origin.y - boundingBox.height,
    width: boundingBox.width,
    height: boundingBox.height
    )
    
    var convertedRect = VNImageRectForNormalizedRect(newOriginBoundingBox, Int(rectOfImage.width), Int(rectOfImage.height))
    
    /// add the margins
    convertedRect.origin.x += rectOfImage.origin.x
    convertedRect.origin.y += rectOfImage.origin.y
    
    return convertedRect
}
```

This takes into account the frame of the image view and also `aspect fill` content mode.

Example (I'm using a static image instead of a live camera feed for simplicity):

```
/// inside your Vision request completion handler...
guard let image = self.imageView.image else { return }

let convertedRect = self.getConvertedRect(
    boundingBox: observation.boundingBox,
    inImage: image.size,
    containedIn: self.imageView.bounds.size
)
self.drawBoundingBox(rect: convertedRect)

func drawBoundingBox(rect: CGRect) {
    let uiView = UIView(frame: rect)
    imageView.addSubview(uiView)
        
    uiView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    uiView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
    uiView.layer.borderWidth = 3
}
```

<kbd>[image: Image taller than image view, orange bounding box drawn on detected rectangle]</kbd>

<kbd>[image: Image wider than image view, orange bounding box drawn on detected rectangle]</kbd>

I made an example project [here](https://github.com/aheze/CardScanner/tree/7f15c9ac143f27d56e890095ef896d2a9f851948).

Comment: How to calculate the regionOfInterest correctly? In my case the cameraPreview frame is CGRect(0.0, 780.0, 810.0, 300.0) for iPad 8th Gen, and the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayerInstance.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill. It fills video output by skiping some portion from top and bottom by keeping aspect ratio. I am looking for a solution to scan the barcodes which displays inside the preview, currently it is scanning the barcode which are not showing in preview when barcode image is outside of top/bottom direction. Please provide answer for this.