# Xcode Swift 5 scanning barcodes with AVfoundation, how to pause and add a button to resume scan without stopping or closing the view

Tags: swift, xcode, avfoundation, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I'm following this tutorial http://www.wepstech.com/bar-qr-code-ios-with-swift-5/

to add a QRcode / Bar Code Scanner.

The view starts with the camera capture, when it detects it print to console

```
func found(code: String) {
        print(code)
    }
```

and stop `avCaptureSession.stopRunning()`

Is there a way to add buttons and at scan just "pause" and click on a button "resume" to scan an other box.

In real life situation (example), the staff at the warehouse receives many box, sometimes with serial number, but some times small items without serial numbers...

so the logic would be open the scanner app, camera begins, scan->followed by pause-> staff change the phone near next box, and hit resume. all this without the camera to stop and close the view.

so 2 questions

•1• How to pause the scan without closing the view ?

•2• How to make the camera preview not full screen ? (to add the buttons and text label showing the user the scanned barcode...)

Comment: To pause the camera, `avCaptureSession.stopRunning()` is fine. To make it not full screen, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66054211/14351818) might be helpful for converting the coordinates.

Comment: @aheze and what would the resume look like

Comment: `avCaptureSession.startRunning()`