# Convert points from Vision coordinates to UIKit coordinates in VNDetectHumanHandPoseRequest

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, coreml, apple-vision

I'm trying to implement Detecting Hand Poses with Vision in `ARSCNView`. I've successfully made the `VNDetectHumanHandPoseRequest` and get detected hand poses result and convert vision coordinates to AVFoundation coordinates but now I want to convert that `AVFoundation` coordinates to `UIKit` coordinates to visualization that detect point.

I've reviewed that the apple provided demo example for the Detecting Hand Poses and see the logic for converting AVFoundation coordinates to UIKit coordinates through `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` class `captureDevicePointConverted` method.

Here is the code snippet:

```
let previewLayer = cameraView.previewLayer
let thumbPointConverted = previewLayer.layerPointConverted(fromCaptureDevicePoint: thumbPoint)
```

I want to know how I can convert points using `ARSCNView` because there is no preview layer found in the `ARCamera`.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66054211/14351818

Comment: @aheze Thanks for the replay but I don't have a bounding box because  VNDetectHumanHandPoseRequest does not provide a bounding box as result. here is the logic I implemented and what I want. check this https://prnt.sc/1990aez

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on Github, the person uses :

VNImagePointForNormalizedPoint(CGPoint(x: $0.location.y, y: $0.location.x), Int(self.arView.bounds.width),  Int(self.arView.bounds.height))

$0 represents each of the recognized points.

Here is the link to the code: https://github.com/john-rocky/RealityKit-Sampler/blob/main/RealityKitSampler/UIKitViews/HandInteractionARViewController.swift